# How to pass a list variable in python_terraform module

Tags: python-3.x, terraform

I have the following code

```
from python_terraform import *

acc_id = "888888888888"
managed_account_list = [555555555555, 222222222222, acc_id]
    tf = Terraform(working_dir='/{0}/aws-organization/organizations/terraform/account_global'.format(cwd),
                   variables={'managed_accounts': managed_account_list})
    global_workspace = "prod" + '.' + account
    tf.set_workspace(global_workspace)
    tf.init()
    tf.plan(out='plan.out')
    output = tf.apply(no_color=IsFlagged, refresh=False, skip_plan=True)
    pprint.pprint(output)
```

but this does not seem to work
please could someone help me with the syntax to pass a list variable in the above **variables** section

Comment: "does not seem to work" is not specific. Why exactly it does not work? What happens and what should happen normally? What are error messages?

Comment: @Marcin - actually in the background I have couple of terraform scripts (12) and this python script is acting as a wrapper where it should pass a list of managed_accounts for the terraform to create tag enforcement lambda jobs for each of these accounts, but this does not happen though i get no error. But the same terraform script works as expected if I enter the values manually in a terraform locals

Comment: Could you edit your question so that the code forms a [mcve] please? That way people can see what you've tried and test it themselves or more easily see where your problem is. It would also help if your question includes any errors that you get or explains how it's not doing what you want it to do and show what it does do instead.

Comment: Does this issue still persist?

Comment: yes I am still looking for a solution

Comment: @Marcin Do you have any pointers for this?